# tabs in android

Tags: android, tabs, tabwidget

In my android app, Tab Bar has 3 tabs in it in Tabs activity . 
There is another activity like notification  whenever user is on this activity i want to create 3 different tabs.

e.g tab1, tab2 and tab3, These are the three tabs in tabs activity. tab1 has submit button. After click on submit button, it should go to the next activity.I am able to get to the next activity but that activity is coming in current activity. I have used activity group so that i am able to get the next activity call. Now as tab1 activity calls tab2 activity the tab2 should go to the selected state of tab.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this [article](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.com/2010/09/adding-tabs-dynamically.html) will help you to get started about how to add tabs dynamically.